# How can I fix this chrome autofill extension issue?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, stripe-payments, webapi

```
chrome.storage.local.get('CNumber', function (data) {
            console.log(data.CNumber);
            fill('cardNumber', data.CNumber);
        });
```

So im writing an auto fill extension and right now i'm working on the stripe module. I've already done the shopify version which works perfectly, so I thought the only difference would be the tags for the elements and what not. The code above is a snippet of the code I use to fill a text field like the card number field. Here is the fill function:

```
function fill(elementId, assignment) {
    let element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    console.log(element);
    if (element != null) {
        element.focus();
        element.value = assignment;
        console.log("successfully filled");
        element.blur();
    }
}
```

Now my issue is that variable "element" in the fill function is returning null on this page: [here](https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/ppage_1H3mzRFKnpzPB0MXgP2ZUpNl#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWm9CPHY2XUhhVm9fQzxOYWgwYjA8f2lcYScpJ3dgY2B3d2B3SndsYmxrJz8nbXFxdXY%2FKip2cXdsdWArZmpoJyknaWpmZGlgJz9rcGlpKSdobGF2Jz9%2BJ2JwbGEnPycwZ2BjPDY2PShkNzNnKDFmZjcoPDAyYSgxYTQ9MGFkZjFgZGcnKSdocGxhJz8nNjw2ZzdgPDMoPWMyYygxN2Q2KGQ2Mj0oMzI8MzQ9MGc2Zjc0JykndmxhJz8nZjxhYDVjYDcoMzFjNigxPDBmKD01MTQoY2Q3PGM2YGM0N2Y9J3gpJ2dgcWR2Jz9eWHgl) even though the element clearly exists with that matching id.

Comment: `stripe.js` puts the input elements in an iframe.

Comment: This seems really dangerous. Can you say more about why the credit card number would be stored in local storage? That seems very insecure and likely not supported by Stripe elements.

Comment: @cjav_dev where else would it be stored?

Comment: Only in secure PCI compliant infrastructure that has passed rigorous security review.